# Vertically center div inside ion-slides

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic 2 for making an mobile application. I want to add 2 buttons (next, previous) inside a slideshow of images (which I got from the internet), but I don't know how can I vertically center those buttons inside Ion sliders.

Here is what I have to do:

[image: demonstration]

Comment: are you using AngularJS in your project?

Comment: i'm using ionic2 with typescript

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I believe I found what you need.

To achieve your objective, I suggest you use [angular swiper](https://github.com/ksachdeva/angular-swiper). Angular swiper is an AngularJS library, but it is compatible with ionic.

To use it, I recommend the following tutorial:

- http://www.gajotres.net/how-to-create-elegant-slider-carousel-in-ionic-framework/

This library has a ton of functionalities, including (but not limited) to the arrows you want.

The source code for the functionality you want can be found in the following link:

- https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/blob/master/demos/14-nav-arrows.html

Comment: thanks Flame_Phoenix :)